# Excel VBA: How to run two codes with the same button

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and I really need your help. I want to run the following separate codes with the same button (one code copies the information from a worksheet to another, the other code adds checkboxes according to the last copied cell with data):

```
Sub CopyInfo()
Dim i As Integer
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim Search As String
Dim Column As Integer

Sheets("Audit").Activate
Sheets("Audit").Range("A1").Select
'Sets an Autofilter to sort out only your Yes rows.
Selection.AutoFilter
'Change Field:=5 to the number of the column with your Y/N.
 Sheets("Audit").Range("$A$1:$G$2000").AutoFilter Field:=5,   Criteria1:="Yes"

'Finds the last row
 LastRow = Sheets("Audit").Cells(Sheets("Audit").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

i = 1
'Change the 3 to the number of columns you got in Sheet2
 Do While i <= 3
 Search = Sheets("Form").Cells(1, i).Value
 Sheets("Audit").Activate
 'Update the Range to cover all your Columns in Sheet1.
 If IsError(Application.Match(Search, Sheets("Audit").Range("A1:G1"), 0)) Then
    'nothing
 Else
    Column = Application.Match(Search, Sheets("Audit").Range("A1:G1"), 0)
    Sheets("Audit").Cells(2, Column).Resize(LastRow, 1).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Form").Activate
    Sheets("Form").Cells(2, i).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
 End If
 i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

AND

```
Sub Checkbox()
 Dim ToRow As Long
 Dim LastRow As Long
 Dim MyLeft As Double
 Dim MyTop As Double
 Dim MyHeight As Double
 Dim MyWidth As Double
'--------------------------
 LastRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
 For ToRow = 2 To LastRow
     If Not IsEmpty(Cells(ToRow, "A")) Then
        '-
        MyLeft = Cells(ToRow, "C").Left
        MyTop = Cells(ToRow, "C").Top
        MyHeight = Cells(ToRow, "C").Height
        MyWidth = MyHeight = Cells(ToRow, "C").Width
        '-
        ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(MyLeft, MyTop, MyWidth, MyHeight).Select
         With Selection
            .Caption = "Yes"
            .Value = xlOff
            .LinkedCell = "E" & ToRow
            .Display3DShading = False
         End With
     End If
     Next
     End Sub
```

Thank you for your help. I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call the two procedures (`Sub`) into a third one:

```
Sub Copysheet_And_CheckBox() '<-- you run this
  Copysheet '<-- you call this first
  Checkbox '<-- and this second into the same call
End Sub`
```

Comment: @MatteoNNZ - you have substantially improved my original answer.  If you want to repost your improvements as a new answer, I will delete this one and vote yours up.

Comment: The answer is yours, so I'll rather vote yours up ;). But please for the next time, remember that not anyone has the same knowledge, so in the spirit of SO, when you write an answer try to add some more explanation for the others to understand better the logic behind.

Comment: It did not work exactly like I wanted. Could you post the whole code and maybe run it at your end. I might doing something wrong. What the first code does it that it copies the information to a new sheet if the text is "YES" in column E. Then what the other code does is that it add a check box in the new sheet in Column C according to the number of pasted values in that sheet.